# Animation on bootstrap navbar width

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css, css-transitions, navbar

I'm trying to build a header menu with the boostrap navbar. For the moment I have my navbar, and on scroll I add the class navbar-fixed-top, the navbar cover the full width of the page, everything's fine.

Now I want to add an animation on the width changing as [we can see here](http://qantumthemes.com/demo/onair/music-charts-archive/)

I tried to add a css transition effect on the navbar-fixed-top class but nothing changes.
my HTML structure:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container">
                ....
            </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

my CSS code:

```
.navfixed{
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
}
```

and my JQuery:

```
var offset = $(".navbar").offset().top;
$(document).scroll(function(){
    var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
    if(scrollTop > offset){
        $(".navbar").addClass("navbar-fixed-top");


    }
    else {
       $(".navbar").removeClass("navbar-fixed-top");
    }
});
```

If you have an idea.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
```

Instead Of

```
var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
```

Or You can also use

```
var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
```

See the Full Code Here:

```
var offset = $(".navbar").offset().top;
$(document).scroll(function(){
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(scrollTop > offset){
        $(".navbar").addClass("navbar-fixed-top");


    }
    else {
       $(".navbar").removeClass("navbar-fixed-top");
    }
});
```

This Might Be Helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't change anything